# How to use Tomcat 7 as a React development server to replace a Node.js server?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, npm, tomcat7

Hi I am using Tomcat 7 to host my JavaEE project, and Node.js for my React app. I want to replace the node server with Tomcat 7 and use it as React development server.

Comment: Do you plan on keeping your already running Java EE project or you want to just have a tomcat server that supports your react app?

Comment: You could deploy the ReactJS app on Tomcat. Did you try?